# Error with material design element in instrumented test

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-styles

I have the following instrumented test:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testReactToGameStatusError() {
        var fragmentScenario = launchFragment<CreateGameFragment>(
            initialState = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
        )
        fragmentScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            val gson = Gson()
            var errorResponse = ErrorResponse("", 0, "TestError", "TestMessage", "")
            val errorResponseString = gson.toJson(errorResponse).toString()
            fragment.reactToGameStatus(errorResponseString, null)
            Truth.assertThat(fragment.m_CreateGameError).isTrue()
            Truth.assertThat(fragment.m_CreateGameErrorString.contains("TestMessage"));
        }

        fragmentScenario.close()
    }
```

This tests the fragment CreateGameFragment. The fragments runs in the application in the emulators as well as on devices.
But when I run this test I get the following error:

```
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

before that in the stack:

```
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.internal.CheckableImageButton
```

and before that:

```
Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040003 a=-1}
```

The dependency of the material theme is set in the build.gradle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

In the layout the input button is defined as follows:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInput_gamename"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/gamename_edittext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/ModifiedEditText"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:hint="@string/game_name"
                    android:text="@={settingsData.m_GameName}" />
      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The style is defined as follows:

```xml
    <style name="ModifiedEditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">?planesBackgroundEndColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?planesToolbarForegroundColor</item>
    </style>
```

What I have tried:

1. Used a MaterialComponents style instead of AppCompat for ModifiedEditText and for the whole app
2. Raised SDK Level from 21 to 23
3. Used themeResId Parameter in launchFragment. Here I did not find many resources in internet and did not succeed to give the id of the actual app theme as parameter. So maybe this is a possible solution but I am not able to define a suitable resource id. The app theme is defined as follows:

```
 <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Can anyone please give me a hint in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to give the style of the fragment in the method onGetLayoutInflater of the fragment as follows:

```
override fun onGetLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): LayoutInflater {
        if (activity is MainActivity)
            return super.onGetLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)

        val inflater = super.onGetLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)
        val contextThemeWrapper: Context = ContextThemeWrapper(requireContext(), R.style.MyAppTheme)
        return inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper)
    }
```

The first test in the method looks if the fragment was created by the app in order to use in this case the theme as defined for the activity in the Android Manifest.